# error message in R when using samr

Tags: r, runtime-error

I have been using SAM(Significance analysis of microarrays) in R, when my program runs it got halted when performing the operations using the sam instruction. The messages that displays are:

```
Cluster size 12488 broken into 6032 6456 
Cluster size 6032 broken into 2628 3404 
Cluster size 2628 broken into 1051 1577
```

In some datasets it appears those messages, but the processing continues without no problem at all; while in others the program hangs. R does not display any message, but the one that displays those messsages of Cluster broken is Rstudio.

The sam instruction that I am using is something like:

```
samfit <- SAM(t, numbas, resp.type="Two class unpaired",
                         nperms=100, 
                         testStatistic=c("standard"),
                         knn.neighbor=10, 
                         random.seed=1234567, 
                         logged2=TRUE,
                         genenames=rownames(t))
```

Does anybody came with that error before maybe without using sam for R? I have made a search in google, but I have not found anything about it

Thanks

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: You have not shown the actual message. It does not look like an error but rather a warning. Is the word "Error" actually in the message?

Comment: thank you for your reply @DWin, the problem is that after that message the R hangs, even RStudio, asks to reboot and the Windows shows a message of a crash exception

Comment: I dont know if I can attach the code that I have and a sample csv file in an external file server because is huge, is that allowed here in this site?

Comment: So the problem is that R abends and no error-message is displayed. Those are just messages of information during `SAM`'s normal operation. What happens when you contact the package maintainer?